# How to redirect if URL contains certain word?

Tags: .htaccess

Project has folder **API** where two files named `index.php` and `mobile.php`.
`index.php` is contains APIs for web platform and `mobile.php` for mobile devices.

I have this problem. If code will do response to `/api/get-courses`, htaccess should redirect to `index.php` file. If response url has `/api/mobile.php/get-courses` mobile.php word, it shoul be redirected to `mobile.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} mobile\.php
RewriteRule ^ mobile.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

There i have tried to do implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what you actually mean by "If code will do response to ..." ... If that refers to a request to that URL which your want to internally rewrite, then this should do what you ask:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?api/get-courses$ /index.php [END,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?api/mobile\.php/get-courses$ /mobile.php [END,QSA]
```

This implements an internal *rewrite*, *not* a redirection. I assume this is what you actually want, according to the wording in your question. If I miss understood what you actually ask then you need to take the time to revise your question to be more precise...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).